# Why pcov in optimize.curve_fit is a two by two matrix and which value corresponds to intercept

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to understand perr in the following code which is a matrix with dimensions(2,2).I was expecting it as a matrix with dimensions(1,2). Can you please explain which value correspond to slope and which value correspond to intercept. Documentation says that diagonals are the variance in the parameters(slope,intercept). What about off diagonal elements?what the tell us?

```
x= np.arange(10)
y = np.array([2,4,7,8,11,18,20,24,26,28])

def line(x,m,b):   #m and b are parameters
    return m*x+b

pfit,perr = optimize.curve_fit(line,x,y)
error = []
for i in range(len(pfit)):
    gg=np.absolute(perr[i][i])**0.5
    print (gg)
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) is pretty clear what it returns as `popt` and `pcov`. And says that `pcov` will be a 2d array. What part of the documentation is unclear? The two values of `pfit` are the slope (`m`) and intercept (`b`), so you could plot `x` versus `line(x, *pfit)`.

Comment: in pcov first rows contains two elements. documentation says that diagonals of this matrix are the variance of parameter estimate. What about off diagonal elements. what they stand for?

Comment: Please clarify the part of the question asking "*why we ignore 0 values of covariance and why we divide it by 0.5?*". I can see neither any ignored 0-values nor a division by 0.5 in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters are represented in the result in the same order that the optimized function takes them. Since line is defined as `line(x, m, b)`, `popt` contains the estimates in the order `[m, p]`.

The `pcov` (or `perr` in the example) that `curve_fit` returns is the [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) of the estimated parameters.

- The diagonal elements are the variances. They tell us how likely the parameter is to vary, or how confident we are in the estimate. A large variance basically means we don't know very much about the parameter; the value returned in `popt` is the *most likely* value, but even far-away values are also very likely.
- The off-diagonal elements are the [covariances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance). Their meaning is actually hidden in the name: co-variance; how variables vary together.

This is what different covariance values mean:

```
      covariance | two variables are...
     ------------+-----------------------
               0 | not related at all
               1 | exactly the same
              -1 | exactly inverted
 between 0 and 1 | one is likely to be large when the other is also large
between 0 and -1 | one is likely to be large when the other is small
```

In the example the covariance matrix is

```
[[ 0.025, -0.114],
 [-0.114,  0.723]]
```

So what does it mean that the covariance of slope and intercept is -0.114? They are related: if the intercept is large the slope must be smaller and vice versa.

Graphically, if you move the whole line upwards it must have less slope to be near the data points; if you move it down it needs more slope.
[image]

This is pretty obvious in linear regression and therefore not that useful; but keep in mind that `curve_fit` can take any complicated function where dependence between parameters is not that obvious. In that case this may be valuable information.

Comment: Thanks alot now I got it

Answer (score 0):

pcov : 2d array

The estimated covariance of popt. The diagonals provide the variance of the parameter estimate. To compute one standard deviation errors on the parameters use perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)).

You are talking about the variance and covariance of the parameters, not the variables.

The covariance, defined in the values ​​that are not on the diagonal, tells us how much and in what direction a parameter will run if I choose the other, larger or smaller.

The standard deviation tells us that within the range [mean-std, mean + std] there is a 68% chance that the value being measured is in that range.

The variance tells us how scattered the values ​​are